# Why location permission pop up not showing in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I want to implement get current location in react native. I put permission to activate location if location is not activate in phone before calling geolocation API but pop up not showing and this  `PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,{ title: 'Location Access Required', message: 'This App needs to Access your location'},);` always return "granted" when request permission using `PermissionAndroid` module.

this is my code

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

...

componentDidMount(){
    
    const requestLocationPermission = async () => {
      let geoOptions = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout:20000,
        maximumAge: 60*60*24
      }

      try {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
          PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
          {
            title: 'Location Access Required',
            message: 'This App needs to Access your location',
          },
        );
        console.warn(granted);
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
     Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.geoLocationSuccess,this.geoLocationFailure,geoOptions);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.warn(err);
      }
    };
    requestLocationPermission();
  }
```

is my implementation is wrong ? because i want to show pop up when location service is not enable to let user enable it

Comment: So you're saying that the status is always returning `granted`, even if it isn't?

Comment: yes. when i tried to check value of variable "granted" is always return granted and not showing pop up to let user give permission @Konstantin

Comment: Can you go into the settings of your phone to make sure that the location setting is not granted there? Because if it's already granted, the popup is not going to appear.

Comment: this module not checking whether location on phone active or not ?

Comment: It is, but if it is already granted, then it's not gonna show the popup, because there is no need for that

Comment: ok. maybe my implementation is wrong because i want to show pop up when location services is not enable and prompt user to enable it from pop up. Do you have any suggestion ? module is supported for both iOS and android.

Comment: Did you check that the app does not have the location permission? Because if it does, just remove, reload the app and if you've configured it correctly, the popup should appear.

Comment: app has permission so popup not showing but its not my expectation and its my fault. i want to show popup when location service is not enable/not active (has allowed permission)

Comment: So remove the permission from the app and look at how your app behaves.

Comment: thank you for answering my question

Answer (score 0):

This may be of little help, first make sure no library location other than react-native-geolocation-service. then if there is no use react hook. you might try this method below.

```
hasLocationPermission = async () => {
  const hasPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
);

if (hasPermission === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
  console.log('lagi req permission');
  return true;
}

const status = await PermissionsAndroid.check(
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
);

if (status) {
  console.log('permission diberikan');
  return true;
}

if (status === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.DENIED) {
  ToastAndroid.show(
    'Location permission denied by user.',
    ToastAndroid.LONG,
  );
} else if (status === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.NEVER_ASK_AGAIN) {
  ToastAndroid.show(
    'Location permission revoked by user.',
    ToastAndroid.LONG,
  );
}
return false;
};


async componentDidMount() {
  if (await this.hasLocationPermission()) {
  Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        console.log('posisi ditemukan',position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
        this.goToRegion(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      },
      error => {
        Alert.alert(
          'Oopss!',
          error.message,
          [
            {
              text: 'OK',
              onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
            },
          ],
        );
        console.log(error.message);
        this.setState({error: error.message});
      },
      {
        accuracy: {
          android: 'high',
          ios: 'best',
        },
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 15000,
        maximumAge: 10000,
        distanceFilter: 0,
        forceRequestLocation: true,
        forceLocationManager: false,
        showLocationDialog: true,
      },
    );
  }
}
```